# Is there a way to have Cortana always listening to my commands, without "Hey Cortana"?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Is there a way to avoid saying "Hey, Cortana" before every command ?

Maybe a phrase that would mean "until I say stop, consider all my sentences as commands". Getting her attention every time can be annoying when you have several orders to give.

Of course, there would also be a command to stop the constant listening and get back to "Hey Cortana–ing".

Comment: This isn't a feature of Cortana at this time